# Help with sql join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table 1:
ID, PersonCode, Name,

Table 2:
ID, Table1ID, Location, ServiceDate

I've got a query joining table 1 to table 2 on table1.ID = table2.Table1ID where PersonCode = 'XYZ'

What I want to do is return Table1.PersonCode,Table1.Name, Table2.Location, Table2.ServiceDate, I don't want all rows, In table 2 I'm only interested in the row with the most recent ServiceDate for each location.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.PersonCode, Table1.Name, Table2.Location, MAX(Table2.ServiceDate)
FROM
    Table1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID 
WHERE
    TABLE1.PersonCode = 'XYZ'
GROUP BY
    Table1.PersonCode,Table1.Name, Table2.Location
```

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN? I thought INNER JOIN is suffient?

I would modify your query - Please see my answer below

Comment: Sorry I was working on another question with left joins - edited

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX(ServiceDate)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select Table1.PersonCode,Table1.Name, Table2.Location, Table2.ServiceDate
from Table1
join Table2 on table1.ID = table2.Table1ID 
where table1.PersonCode = 'XYZ'
and table2.ServiceDate = (select max(t2.ServiceDate)
                          from   table2 t2
                          where  t2.table1ID = table2.table1ID
                          and    t2.location = table2.location
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `INNER JOIN` and select the first record, having ordered the records in reverse chronological order based on Table2.ServiceDate.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Table1.PersonCode, Table1.Name, Table2.Location, Table2.ServiceDate
FROM
    Table1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID 
WHERE
    TABLE1.PersonCode = 'XYZ'
ORDER BY Table2.ServiceDate DESC
GROUP BY
    Table1.PersonCode,Table1.Name, Table2.Location
```